# Changing notice period from 1 month to 3 months

Tags: india, notice-period

I joined my current firm 1 year back in 2022 November to nee precise.
When I joined, they have not shared any employee handbook or anything, but by February 2023 they came up with new rules and regulations saying employees must serve a one month notice period after the employer had accepted the resignation letter.
I was okay with it
They also put something,that employer has all the right to change the rules and regulations

When it came to 2024 they put up another set of rules and regulations stating they have revised the notice period to 90 days instead of 30 days, if not serving that ,the employee should pay 3 month salary to the employee.
My question is whether such a notice period extension applicable to me
As there was no notice period mentioned in my offer letter or so.

Comment: What jurisdiction are you in? But it seems that you agreed in February 2023 that your employer had the right to change the rules, so...

Comment: @PhilipKendall So what happens when they change the rules again so that you have to give 60 years' notice, but they will make an exception if you want to retire at 75?

Comment: @SimonB That's precisely why the poster needs to say what jurisdiction they're in; in _my_ jurisdiction (England and Wales), they would get laughed out of court if they tried to enforce it.

Comment: Aviator, tell us the jurisdiction. In most countries the employee would go to court and the court would kick the company in its posterior.

Comment: In most juristictions, changing facts of a contract needs *both* parties approval as a legal minimum for society to function. However, for example in the US, if you can be fired at-will and for any reason, you have zero protections if you disapprove, making this legal minimum pretty pointless. So there is no good answer globally, you will have to add a country tag to get localized advise.

Comment: Even 30 days notice is longer than US standard, as another example of why country matters.

Comment: Hi I am from India so Indian jurisdiction

Comment: Guessed it was India. I do _not_ understand India's employment practices; there are many things just plain odd about them, to the point where I've given up and just ignore questions tagged India.

Answer (score 3):

In these types of question, without location information, the only answer could be

**Contact Local Employment Lawyer**  :)